# Samba DC with additional DNS server (not same server)

Tags: bind, internal-dns, samba4

I need to add a Samba DC to an existing network AND existing DNS Server.
My environment:

- DNS Server with Bind9 (9.10)
- new Samba DC installed with samba-tool and internal DNS Server
- a bunch of servers where the DNS server is the Bind DNS server

Now my question is how can I connect the existing DNS server with my new Samba DC for full functionality?
I think a DNS forward from the Samba DNS server to the Bind DNS server is not enough, right?
Is there something like zone replication necessary?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Set up your DC to be forwarder for your AD domain in your DNS config.

So if your AD domain is called test.lan you would have an entry in your config for your 
BIND in the file where you have your local zones defined you add:

```
zone "test.lan." {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders { 10.10.10.10; };
};
```

where 10.10.10.10 is your DC and then your clients will ask the dns and the dns will forward it to your DC.

Now mind you there are some shortcomings of the internal samba DNS: 
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/DNS_Administration#Known.2Fissues_missing_features 
but most things like dynamic updates and so on will work with this method.